# Am I supposed to be able to favorite my own questions?

Tags: support, challenges

Am I supposed to be able to favorite my own question? It doesn't seem right...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Favouriting a question simply means you want to see notifications of any new answers or edits to that question. ([More info here.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/53585/13)) So it's not a problem to favourite your own questions.

Comment: It also helps you find particular ones if you've asked a lot of questions, since the 'questions' tab can get quite crowded.